# PyDev in OSX creates multiple settings.py/urlspy when creating a new project

Tags: django, macos, pydev

I am trying to start a new project with Django in Pydev, when I create it, I get the following structure:

```
ProjectName
 | ProjectPkg
 |  | ProjectPkg
 |  |  | __init__.py
 |  |  | settings.py
 |  |  | urls.py
 |  | __init__.py
 |  | settings.py
 |  | urls.py
 |  | manage.py
```

Why do I get two ProjectPkg pakages? And why do I have two settings.py/urls.py (only the inner ones work). I gess this is a bug, but anyone has noticed it? I didn't get any clue from googling around...
I have tried creating manually the files and then making a new project in pydev using those files, but pydev creates the missing files to create the same annoying structure.
In Windows it works jst fine. Anyone has an idea of what might be going on and/or how to solve it?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Kind of looks like django-admin.py startproject is being run twice... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/django-admin/#startproject-projectname-destination.  Any way you can see what comamnds pydev is running?

Comment: Actually tried it after reading your comment and startproject creates the same profile. Odd, because I *have* created projects with my computer earlier and it didn't happen.

Comment: Weird... I can't replicate that behaviour using django-admin from terminal?!

Comment: Well, I already solved it. It turns out it was a fault of django. I had to reinstall django and it solved my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is really a strange behavior. Did you already tried to let Django create your folder files, and then only importing the project folder created by Django as a PyDev project. See my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12547097/django-project-console-management-coding-in-eclipse/12547811#12547811) which explains how to do it.

Comment: Yep, tried it and it simply creates the missing (superfluous) files so as to match the structure that I wrote earlier.

Comment: Thus it has probably something to do with your Django setup, not with PyDev, as both approaches lead to the same result and PyDev likely uses Django to create the folder structure. Since thousands of people using Django without getting a double folder structure, it is likely, that your setup is wrong and it is highly unlikely that it is a bug in Django.

Comment: No, I mean, Django creates the folder structure correctly. When creating the new project and including the folder, PyDev messes it up.

Comment: hmm... I'm running PyDev in macosX and did it multiple times without problems. Did you only executed the following steps? Create new project using Django, go to Eclipse, File -> New -> PyDevProject -> Deselect "use default" and choose for input "Directory" the folder which has been created by Django as your project folder, give it a name and click finish. These are the steps I just executed at my setup and PyDev did not create any additional .py files, but only some Eclipse relevant hidden files.

Comment: Yup, I did all that, and still screws up the setup :( I see I have installed python through MacPorts. May that be interfering with PyDev setup?

Comment: Sorry, just tested running django-admin.py startproject and it *does* create the faulty folder structure. Sorry for the misinformation! I'm going to try and reinstall django and see what happens